# Arduino - Android data transfer throughout HC-06 socket problem

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth, arduino-uno

Evening fellow programmers,
am relatively new to android studio, and it's my first time dealing with bluetooth, receivers, broadcasts and such stuff.. I followed some tutorials and created my monitoring app, the app is supposed to read data sent by HC-06 module from arduino, yet I had a pump with the connect thread, it keeps catching the socket.close() instead of trying the socket.connect() and I have no idea why is that happening.. 
here is the code for my ConnectThread.run():

```
public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
        mmDevice = device;
        deviceUUID = uuid;
    }

    public void run(){
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket 
using UUID: "
                    +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket 
" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mmSocket = tmp;

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();

            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection 
in socket " + e1.getMessage());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + 
MY_UUID_INSECURE );
        }


        connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
    }
```

And the thrown exception:

```
D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@3390c6f, mSocketState: INIT
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: Closed Socket.
run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
connected: Starting.
```

However, connectedThread continues to work even when the socket is closed, idk if that's how it works, but here is the ConnectedThread.run():

```
public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);

                Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage",incomingMessage);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And its exceptions:

```
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectedThread: Starting.
E/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Error reading Input Stream. socket closed
```

Comment: You might wanna play around with the UUID that you're using to connect two devices. That might be the only reason for this to occur. As you've not mentioned it how you're getting UUID, I can't reflect much here. But make sure you're using the same UUID which the target device has.

Comment: I actually spent some time looking for the HC-06 UUID and figured it is the same UUID used for most of the sensors, also I used the getUuid() but it didn't work either.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.java) might help you out.

Comment: @Jay it's actually the tutorial I followed, yet it is built to connect 2 smartphones, so the UUID can be randomly generated with no problems, the problem is the HC-06 is a chipset bluetooth module connected to the arduino uno, I don't think the problem is with the UUID, I read some articles about constructing a fallback function or something like that, I just want someone to confirm if that may help